# How to delete duplicate lists of vectors (in any order) from a list of lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, linear-algebra, vector

I have a list of vectors:

v={{{0,0,0},{0,0,1},{1,1,0}},

{{1,0,0},{1,1,1},{0,1,1}},

{{0,0,1},{0,0,0},{1,1,0}}}

Clearly, the first entry and the third entry contain the same vectors. I want to delete one of the duplications but I am not sure how to do this.

I can tell that there is a duplication from

```
DuplicateFreeQ[v]
```

which returns True

However, any of the ways that I know how to delete duplicate cases involve having at least 2 different sets. I am not sure how to do this internally?

I tried using DeleteCases and OrderlessPatternSequence but I cannot seem to get it to look through the elements of v and delete duplicate lists that have the same vectors in different orders?

The only thing I can do is

```
If[MatchQ[Sort[v[[1]]],Sort[v[[3]]],Join[{v[[1]]},{v[[2]]]},v]
```

Which is pretty useless as I'd have to check through each of the rows manually and Join the non-dduplicate rows manually.

Any hints/tips/suggestions welcome. Thanks!

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ v]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `Union`:

```
Union[Sort /@ v]
```

You could also use `DeleteDuplicatesBy`:

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[v, Sort]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this using `GatherBy`and `Union`:

```
GatherBy[Map[Union, v], Union][[All, 1]]

(*{{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}}, {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}}*)
```